# Unable to find a specification for `React-callinvoker` depended upon by `RNReanimated`

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run pod install in the `ios` folder and I get this error.

```
omsonone@Oms-MacBook-Pro ios % pod install 
Ignoring ffi-1.15.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.4
Detected React Native module pods for RNCMaskedView, RNReanimated, RNScreens, react-native-camera, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-save-view
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-callinvoker` depended upon by `RNReanimated`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I tried `pod repo update` but it doesn't help. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Can some one answer this question . This is happening after navigation upgrade from Ver 4 to ver 5